# android HttpRequest to another android device

Tags: android, http, request

I am trying to make a simple android application, in order to make http requests between 2 android devices. The principle is the following:

The two android devices are running the same application. One device will make a http request to the other android device which will listen on a specified port, and the latter will respond to the first one with a response message like "OK", "Not received" etc. Basically, I have a form with name, firstname, address etc. and I want to send these with Http Request, and have a response  to this request for acknowledging. I googled around for a couple of hours, all I could find were some examples with HttpRequest, but these were used when we want to make a HttpRequest to a website. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: read about java socket programming

Comment: Done that, the problem is that I really need to do this via HTTP requests.

Comment: so you need a http server on the device, are you really sure you want it?

Comment: Exactly, that's exactly what I want. I just need a tiny tiny tiny web server that listens on a port (say 8080), whereas another device will try to communicate with the first one via HttpRequests. I know this is weird, but it is a constraint imposed for a project at school. I have been googling around and I found some projects like NanoHtttpD or i-Jetty, but what I need is MUCH more simpler than that. For example, device 1 listens on port 8080 for HttpRequest, and device 2 makes a Http Request to device 1 which will answer with an "OK" or "Not Found" message

Comment: www.devlper.com/2010/12/a-bare-minimum-web-server-for-android-platform/

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a very bad idea to have a http-server-like process on Android. I would recommend having an intermediate service (a normal web server) that can handle the requests or use Google Cloud Messaging to have the two devices communicate.

Comment: I totally agree, but I really need to do it whis way. It is a constraint.

Comment: Not a problem at all! The OS, by default, optimises IO operations so that the user's battery isn't drained. I wanted to do the exact same thing you did until I found this post: http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/9/18/if-youre-programming-a-cell-phone-like-a-server-youre-doing.html

Best of luck!!